# Insertar en una tabla Mysql que a su vez depende de otras dos tablas

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Estoy tratando de insertar en una tabla denominada **badges_members** que a su vez depende de dos tablas adicionales, una se llama **badges** y la otra **members**.

La tabla badges_members tiene la siguiente estructura:

[image: badges_members]

Y estoy tratando de insertar los últimos badges que fueron dados de alta que son los siguientes de la tabla badges:

[image: badges]

Por cada usuario registrado en la base de datos tiene que existir su respectivo badge en la tabla badges_members, es decir si hay 6 usuarios en la tabla members y 6 badges en la tabla badges, tienen que existir 36 registros en la tabla badges_members, solo por mencionar un ejemplo. Mi tabla members tiene la siguiente estructura:

[image: members]

Actualmente tengo 407 usuarios registrados y los badges nuevos son 6, por lo tanto, se tendrían que insertar 2442 nuevos registros.

Estoy tratando de insertarlos ejecutando la siguiente consulta:

```
INSERT INTO badges_members (user_id, badge_id, active)
SELECT m.id, b.id, 'no' FROM badges_members bm
INNER JOIN members m ON bm.user_id=m.id
INNER JOIN badges b ON bm.badge_id=b.id
WHERE m.id NOT IN(SELECT user_id FROM badges_members)
AND b.id NOT IN(SELECT badge_id FROM badges_members);
```

Que no me muestra ningún error pero tampoco inserta ningún registro.

[image: resultado]

Y si le quito las condiciones a la consulta me muestra el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las llaves primarias de la tabla badges_members estan formadas de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si los badges son nuevos, no necesitas chequear si ya existen en la tabla.  Creo que si tu primary key fuera la cominacion de user_id. badge_id se solucionaria tu problema

Comment: Que es lo que pasa si solo ejecutas desde el `Select`, este deberia de retornar la tabla que deseas insertar..

Comment: No me retorna ningún resultado, por lo mismo quisiera saber si alguna parte del SELECT está mal.

Comment: El tema es que estás haciendo el select a la tabla que quieres insertar y esa relación todavía no existe, no se si me explico estás buscando al revés, tienes que buscar en members los que no tengan bagdes de igual manera para el otro lado, lo que haces ahora es buscar en members_badges, tendrias que tener primero el from members o from badges, otra cosa es que puedes usar Left Join y Rigth Join para obtener cada lado de la relación. Si se te complica mucho me comentas y te coloco el código.

Comment: Hice una consulta de la siguiente manera, pero no me arroja el id:             SELECT m.id, b.id, 'no' FROM badges_members bm
RIGHT JOIN badges b ON  bm.badge_id=b.id
LEFT JOIN members m ON bm.user_id=m.id WHERE b.id >= 23

Comment: Para buscar members sin badges:

`select m.id from members m
Left join badges_members bm on bm.user_id = m.id
where bm.user_id is null;`

Para buscar badges sin miembros:

`select b.id from badges b
Left join badges_members bm on bm.badge_id= b.id
where bm.badge_id is null;`

Answer (score 1):

Lo logre haciendo lo siguiente:

```
INSERT INTO badges_members (user_id, badge_id, active)
SELECT m.id, b.id, 'no' FROM members m, badges b
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM badges_members WHERE user_id=m.id AND badge_id=b.id);
```

Comment: Pues quedó mejor  así. Saludos!